# How to avoid rich blacks on inkjet?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf

I'm printing a short-run of labels at home on my Epson Inkjet.

I have a CMYK pdf I've exported from Illustrator.  No rich blacks, no color conversion when creating the pdf, Appearance of Black: both options are set to "accurate".

I've opened the pdf in photoshop and looked at the Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow channels.  Color only exists where I've told it to be (no help from CMY to create blacks).

I still get 4-color blacks when I print! How do I stop this? Is there a way?

If not, is there any way I can get more life out of my ink?
Most of the print is black with some green letters, and I've already had to replace Cyan after less than 40 glossy pages, and Magenta is almost empty.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it has been my experience that most printers will print in full color if there is any color on the print job. To avoid this you would need to print in black and white or grayscale.

**Extended life:** Try printing in draft mode. This will give a quick print and will use considerably less ink. It will also result in a lower quality print.

**Possible workaround:** Is it possible for you to turn off "black" elements in your design and print color, then enable the black elements and print in monochrome or grayscale? This would require careful alignment in your printer and may return less than favorable results....